# Banner width is not fixed by browser size

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a similar problem as Stackoverflow.com web site has. The problem is width a banner above the content or body of the web site. I want to be able to reduce the width of the browser page but **keep** the size of the banner no matter what resolution is running the browser.

Example, if you reduce the width of this page you will see that a scroll bar will appear so you can move the page to the right and see the content hide. However, if you look at the banner the banner will have the new width that was reduced the page.

[image: Example of reducing browser width and banner is not displaying properly]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand correctly may be you can define **min-width** in to the body. Write like this:

```
body{
 min-width:975px;
}
```

It's mostly happened when the element have **auto width** & his **parent** didn't have any `width` define.

Comment: That worked. But what you mean with "parent", the Site.Master?

Comment: in that the parent is body. i have recreate the bug check this http://jsfiddle.net/TmuVm/